# VM disk on ESXi 6.7 is taking more space than actual max size

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, disk-space, esxi

I'm having an issue on my ESXi 6.7, I have few VM on which the disk is taking more space on the host than the actually maximum size I provided to the disk, here is what I see on esx :
[Disk on esx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnnWj.png) and here is what I see when the vm is turned off : [Disk vm off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MedX1.png) and this is inside the VM : [Disk space in VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDYnC.png).

As you can see, I create a disk for this vm that have a maximum capacity of 64GB but the disk is currently taking more than 71GB on my host even though the disk is not full, how is this posible? I tried to consolidate my disk and I deleted all the snapshots I had.

The problem is that the disk is growing every day and after a while the disk space on my host will be full. I'm currently at 97% even though I designed all my disks to not saturate my host disk space even if all my vm are taking 100% of the disk space.

If anyone could help me, I would be very grateful, my disk is almost full.

Thank you

Comment: Shrink disk (may fail if not enough free space on host). Disable disk file auto-growth. Remember that disk changes needs disk space too - and out of the disk file. Make disk changes written immediately to disk (undo changes and revert to snapshot possibilities will be lost).

Comment: The space you see used might be for snapshots. Try to consolidate snapshots from the snapshot manager.

Comment: I've already consolidate and even deleted all the snapshot, I will try to export the vm and then import it again. I'm hoping that the disk will be good again after that.